# Keras Running Inference with Multiple Models' at once

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm training models with a genetic algorithm, and the fitness function first builds the model with certain parameters, and then runs inference on the dataset with that model.

Obviously, genetic algorithms are very parallelizable, but I am running into problems loading and running multiple models at once. I am using Python's multiprocessing library and running the function that loads the model and runs inference using the Pool method. I get an error when doing this:

> Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(32, 50), b.shape=(50, 200), m=32, n=200, k=50
>            [[{{node lstm_1/while/body/_1/MatMul_1}}]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_494]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph

Not sure what's happening here, but the error isn't thrown when the models are not parallelized. 
Any help is super appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import regularizers
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, ELU, LSTM, PReLU, GRU, CuDNNGRU, CuDNNLSTM
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math, random, copy, pickle, time, statistics
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp

def buildModel(windowSize):
    #model to use
    sample_model = Sequential()
    sample_model.add(CuDNNLSTM(50, input_shape = (windowSize, 5), return_sequences=False))
    sample_model.add(Dense(50, activation="relu"))
    sample_model.add(Dense(3, activation="softmax"))
    sample_model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy")
    sample_model.build()
    #record weight and bias shape
    modelShape = []
    for i in range(len(sample_model.layers)):
      layerShape = []
      for x in range(len(sample_model.layers[i].get_weights())):
        layerShape.append(sample_model.layers[i].get_weights()[x].shape)
      modelShape.append(layerShape)
    return(sample_model, modelShape)

model = BuildModel(120)
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
results = [pool.apply(model.predict, args=(np.array(features[x]), batch_size=len(features[i]))) for x in range(len(features))]
pool.close()
```

The features I'm using aren't important, they could all be lists of 120 random numbers or something. I didn't actually add the features I use because they are huge and from a really big file.

I just want to be able to run model.predict inside the pool.apply[] multiprocessing function so that I can run multiple predictions concurrently.

Comment: This is going to be difficult to answer without any code.  See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Added code, not sure if it's really helpful though @gobrewers14

Comment: This is not ***reproducible***.  One should be able to copy & paste your code from this question and put it in a python REPL and the code reproduces the error.  Otherwise we're just guessing.  We have no idea what `fitnessFunction`, `modelToUse`, `features`, etc..., are.

Comment: I added code that can be run and reproduced, all that is needed is some random features, but the code conveys the entire problematic part. Let me know if I need to add anything more.